# How can i invoke KeyDown event in the button Click event

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void textBoxColor_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
//do something 
} 
private void btnSaveSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
//how can i invoke the KeyDown event 
}
```

In my test WinForm, i have a TextBox named textBoxColor and a Button named btnSaveSet. I add KeyDown event to the textBox and Click event to the Button.

Comment: Why not just write a method that you call from both event handlers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generally you shouldn't try to call event handlers within other event handlers. If you want to share a method, then you should put it in another method and call that from each of the events.

For example:

```
private void textBoxColor_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
    SomeMethod();
} 

private void btnSaveSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    SomeMethod();
}

private void SomeMethod()
{
    // Put your shared event code here.
}
```

You can also pass the event arguments into this method if you'd like, by adding these as parameters to `SomeMethod`.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple, call method `textBoxColor_KeyDown` from  `btnSaveSet_Click`

```
private void textBoxColor_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) 
{ 
//do something 
} 
private void btnSaveSet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    textBoxColor_KeyDown(sender,null);
}
```